# Error when mount a volume using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### I'm using docker-compose to setup domserver.I can run the domserver successfully using image of dockerhub.However,when I want to mount a directory into the container,it will pop error message like this:

```
dj-domserver_1  | /scripts/start.sh: line 29: cd: /opt/domjudge/domserver: No such file or directory
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVnWW.png

the directory domjudgeKChen is cp from the container that is setup by the image of dockerhub (domserver6.0.3)
this is the domserver part in yml file:

```
dj-domserver:
                image: domjudge/domserver:6.0.3
                volumes:
                        - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
                        - ~/domjudgeKChen/opt/domjudge:/opt/domjudge
                environment:
                        - CONTAINER_TIMEZONE=Asia/Taipei
                        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpw
                        - MYSQL_DATABASE=domjudge
                        - MYSQL_USER=domjudge
                        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=djpw
                networks:
                        dj-db:
                        dj-judgedaemons:
                depends_on:
                  - phpmyadmin
                  - dj-mariadb
                ports:
                        - 9090:80
                links:
                        - dj-mariadb:mariadb
                restart: always
```

and this is the entire .yml file code:

http://codepad.org/7jN5UdG8

### The other question is that I can't setup the judgehost using this yml file.This is the error message when using docker-compose up

```
error: Authentication failed (error 401) while contacting http://domserver/api/v4/judgehosts. Check credentials in restapi.secret.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSEjm.png

If I comment out line 22 in the yml and the domserver can setup using docker-compose up and the mariadb,phpmyadmin would also be fine.

please help me mount the directory into the container and setup the judgehost image successfully.Thanks!

Comment: If your system is spitting out URLs like that, you have a very strange configuration issue.  Can you replace those image links with the actual text of the error you’re getting, and the external link to your YAML file with its actual contents (ideally a minimal extract that demonstrates the issue)?

Comment: Hi,I have edited the post.Hope this helps,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC you must use absolute references for your volumes; you can't use `~`.

Replace `~` in the volume mount with the absolute path and prefix that to `/domjudgeKChen/opt/domjudge` in your volume definition.

Comment: It works!I successfully mount the directory into the container,thanks!

Comment: but it still couldn't setup the judgehost container with this .yml file.it would error like ```judgedaemon[34]: error: Error while executing curl POST to url http://domserver/api/v4/judgehosts/internal-error: http status code: 400, response: {"error":"Invalid argument 'description' for function 'judgehosts#POST'."}``` when I tried to use ```docker-compose up``` how can I fix it?

Comment: Pleased to hear that worked! This is a separate issue|question. Your request is badly formed.